# How to show my app in Notification Access

Tags: android, service, notifications, android-notifications

I know this coding :

`startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS"));`

to intent to `Notification Access` section in `Settings` to `enable/disable the application for granting the permission to get notification or not`.

But my application was not shown in it.

People who know how to register my application in `Notification Access` section in `Settings`,

Please tell me,

Thanks,

*p/s : Here is my Manifest.xml file:*

```
<!-- Application -->
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme" >

        <!-- Activities -->
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".ActivityTDBand" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I add this coding to my manifest file :

```
<!-- Services -->
        <service android:name="controller.BluetoothLeService" />
        <service
            android:name="utils.NotificationListener"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Can see it in `Notification Access` section.